# Return no row if non meets criteria using SUM()

Tags: sqlite

According to documentation Sqlite SUM() function returns NULL if no row in table meets criteria.
I don't want any lines to return if the id does not exist, like in the query:

```
SELECT SUM(tMoney.money),tCustomer.name FROM tMoney JOIN tCustomer ON tMoney.id = tCustomer.id WHERE tCustomer.id = 3
```

tMoney

```
id   money
--- ------
1      210
2      400
1      150
```

tCustomer

```
name    id
--- ------
bob      1
dan      2
```

Comment: SUM() will return NULL only if all values of `money` are NULL for a specific `tMoney.id`. Is this posible?

Comment: @forpas it will also return NULL if WHERE clause asks for non existing row.

Comment: If this is what you ask for then all you need is `group by tCustomer.name` without a HAVING clause, because the WHERE clause will filter out a non existing customer.

Comment: nice, can you explain why group by tCustomer.name removes the row?

Comment: It is not the GROUP BY clause that removes the row. The WHERE clause filters out all the rows since the customer does not exist so there is nothing to be grouped. But, a query that aggregates without a GROUP BY clause, like the query in your question always returns exactly 1 row. This is how SQL deals with such queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just filter out lines with null using "having" clause

```
SELECT SUM(tMoney.money), tCustomer.name 
  FROM tMoney 
  JOIN tCustomer 
    ON tMoney.id = tCustomer.id 
 WHERE tCustomer.id = 3
 group by tCustomer.name 
 having SUM(tMoney.money) is not null;
```